# How to set font color of a label in Java under RGB format?

Tags: java, swing

How do I do something similar.

lblPlay."*set font color under RGB format*"

I use Swing framework.

Thanks.

Comment: What framework do you use ? Swing ? JavaFX ? ...

Comment: Well I tried using .setForeground(Color.X) But, that only shows preset colors. No idea how to input into RGB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you try to change the color of a JLabel inside of swing you can just go with

```
import java.awt.Color;
```

and then use it like

```
yourLabel.setForeground(Color.black) //For example black.
```

or construct the color with

```
yourLabel.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0)) //Provide the r g b values
```

But if you want a more detailed answer you should provide a minimal example with compilable code or atleast describe where exactly the error happens.

Comment: Look at the last code snippet then you see you can change the 0, 0, 0 with your r, g, b values.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
JLabel title = new JLabel("Give me color", JLabel.CENTER);
Color myCustomColor = new Color(100,50,2);
title.setForeground(myCustomColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JavaFX (which you should ;)), use either:

```
label.setTextFill(Color.rgb(red, green, blue));
```

where `red`, `green` and `blue` are integers. Or use:

```
label.setTextFill(Color.web("rrggbb"));
```

where `"rrggbb"` is the typical hexademical RGB representation.